# Sticky long sidebars

Tags: jquery, sticky

I'm trying to figure out how this [website](http://www.fastcolabs.com/) created their sticky sidebar. There's plenty of jQuery tutorials on how to create a position fixed sidebar but none of them specifically address the issue of a long sidebar.

Best code I can come up with so far is this:

```
$(function () {
var lst = 0;
var height = $('.sidebar').height();
var offset = $(".sidebar").offset();
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > lst) { //downscroll
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $(".sidebar").stop().animate({
                marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - 100
            });
        } else {
            $(".sidebar").stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    } else { //upscroll
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < offset.top) {
            $(".sidebar").stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    }
    lst = $(window).scrollTop();
});
});
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/57uP7/). Would greatly appreciate it if someone could help point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just look at their code? Anyway they change its CSS to position: fixed

Comment: yes but how did they detect the mouse position? notice its a long sidebar and not your standard short sidebar

Comment: the mouse position has nothing to do with it. you only have to check how far down the page has been scrolled

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to re-open this post two years after, but for people searching how to sticky a long/huge sidebar it would be helpful. Recycling your code, you have only to adjust two lines and you get the desired effect:

```
$(function () {
    var lst = 0;
    var height = $('.sidebar').height();
    var offset = $(".sidebar").offset();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > lst) { //downscroll
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $(".sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - 100
                });
            } else {
                $(".sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            }
        } else { //upscroll
            if ($(window).scrollTop() < offset.top) {
                $(".sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop()
                });
            }
        }
        lst = $(window).scrollTop();
        offset = $(".sidebar").offset();
    });
});
```

Althoug it's usually coded alternating the css property `position: fixed` and `position: relative`, when you want to scroll and stop the sidebar (as wordpress when editing a post/page do), here is another version when this property is not compatible with our css:

```
$(function () {    
    var lst = 0;
    var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
    var container = sidebar.parent('div').height()+400;
    var height = sidebar.height();
    var offset = sidebar.offset();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).width()>768) {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > lst) { //downscroll
                var bottom_trigger = parseFloat(sidebar.css('paddingTop')) + parseFloat(offset.top) + height;
                if (($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()) > (bottom_trigger) && ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()) < container) {
                    sidebar.css("padding-top", "+=" + ($(window).scrollTop()-lst));
                }
            } else { //upscroll
                var top_trigger = parseFloat(sidebar.css('paddingTop'))+parseFloat(offset.top)-100;
                if ($(window).scrollTop() < top_trigger) {
                    sidebar.css("padding-top", "+=" + ($(window).scrollTop()-lst));
                }

            }
            lst = $(window).scrollTop();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I looked at their code, followed a distinct piece of it which lead me here
http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/grid.php. It looks as though their grid system is almost identical to that of twitter bootstraps, although I have never worked with twitters. The section in that link that concerns you appears to be working with offsets and more importantly Block Grids.